# How to write EasyMock Unit test for http call timeout?

Tags: junit, easymock

```
    final HttpResponse response = this.call(queryUri);
        entity = response.getEntity();public HttpResponse call(final URI queryUri) throws Exception
{
    Future<HttpResponse> futureResponses = executor.submit(new Callable<HttpResponse>()
    {
        @Override
        public HttpResponse call() throws Exception
        {
            final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(queryUri);
            return httpclient.execute(httpget);
        }
    });
    return futureResponses.get(A9_CALL_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

final HttpResponse response = this.call(queryUri);
entity = response.getEntity();
parse(entity.getcontent());
```

wondering how do I mock all the object, can someone provide me the workable code on test class?

Comment: What did you try and what results did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you pull out the creation of the `Callable` to a protected method.

```
public Callable<HttpResponse> createCallable(String queryUri){
  return new Callable<HttpResponse>(){
    @Override
    public HttpResponse call() throws Exception
    {
        final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(queryUri);
        return httpclient.execute(httpget);
    }
});
```

}

I don't think you actually need EasyMock for this test.  In fact it might be easier without it.  In your test you can override this method to return a test stub.   I think if the `get` times out, then it will throw a TimeoutException and not actually cancel the job.  So I think you just need to catch TimeoutException to make sure everything works.

So maybe your mock just has to sleep for `A9_CALL_TIMEOUT` plus some additional fudge factor.

```
@Test
public void testTimeout(){
    Subclass sut = new Subclass(){

          @Override
          public Callable<HttpResponse> createCallable(String queryUri){

            return new Callable<HttpResponse>(){
                  @Override
                   public HttpResponse call() throws Exception{
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(A9_CALL_TIMEOUT *2);
                        catch(InterruptException e) {}
                   }
          });

   };
   //you can also use Junit ExpectedException rule instead
   // of the try catch here
   try{

      sut.runQueryMethodWithExecutor();
      fail("should throw timeout");
   }catch(TimeoutException e){
       //expected
   }
}
```